# Magento 2 - List of payment methods

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

How can I get the list of payment methods that can use in the following?

```
$quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
```

I copied it from a sample online and I guess it is Check / Money Order.

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-all-payment-methods-in-magento-2 all payment methods in Magento

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or you can just..

Inject dependency.

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scope
```

Get value

```
$methodList     = $this->scope->getValue('payment');
```

Iterate over.

```
foreach( $methodList as $code => $_method )
{
    something...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to use payment helper:

```
Magento\Payment\Helper\Data::getPaymentMethods()
```

Add `Magento\Payment\Helper\Data` to the `__construct` method:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data
 */
protected $paymentHelper;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper
) {
    $this->paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
}
```

Then use it to get all payment methods like this:

```
$this->paymentHelper->getPaymentMethods();
```

or:

```
$this->paymentHelper->getPaymentMethodList();
```

Here is this methods:

```
/**
 * Retrieve all payment methods
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getPaymentMethods()
{
    return $this->_initialConfig->getData('default')[self::XML_PATH_PAYMENT_METHODS];
}
```

---

```
/**
 * Retrieve all payment methods list as an array
 *
 * Possible output:
 * 1) assoc array as <code> => <title>
 * 2) array of array('label' => <title>, 'value' => <code>)
 * 3) array of array(
 *                 array('value' => <code>, 'label' => <title>),
 *                 array('value' => array(
 *                     'value' => array(array(<code1> => <title1>, <code2> =>...),
 *                     'label' => <group name>
 *                 )),
 *                 array('value' => <code>, 'label' => <title>),
 *                 ...
 *             )
 *
 * @param bool $sorted
 * @param bool $asLabelValue
 * @param bool $withGroups
 * @param Store|null $store
 * @return array
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function getPaymentMethodList($sorted = true, $asLabelValue = false, $withGroups = false, $store = null)
{
    $methods = [];
    $groups = [];
    $groupRelations = [];

    foreach ($this->getPaymentMethods() as $code => $data) {
        if (isset($data['title'])) {
            $methods[$code] = $data['title'];
        } else {
            $methods[$code] = $this->getMethodInstance($code)->getConfigData('title', $store);
        }
        if ($asLabelValue && $withGroups && isset($data['group'])) {
            $groupRelations[$code] = $data['group'];
        }
    }
    if ($asLabelValue && $withGroups) {
        $groups = $this->_paymentConfig->getGroups();
        foreach ($groups as $code => $title) {
            $methods[$code] = $title;
        }
    }
    if ($sorted) {
        asort($methods);
    }
    if ($asLabelValue) {
        $labelValues = [];
        foreach ($methods as $code => $title) {
            $labelValues[$code] = [];
        }
        foreach ($methods as $code => $title) {
            if (isset($groups[$code])) {
                $labelValues[$code]['label'] = $title;
            } elseif (isset($groupRelations[$code])) {
                unset($labelValues[$code]);
                $labelValues[$groupRelations[$code]]['value'][$code] = ['value' => $code, 'label' => $title];
            } else {
                $labelValues[$code] = ['value' => $code, 'label' => $title];
            }
        }
        return $labelValues;
    }

    return $methods;
}
```